# Clarification of a specific regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I attempted the CoderByte - Simple Symbols - challenge in JavaScript. From CoderByte:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function SimpleSymbols(str)
>   take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is an
>   acceptable sequence by either returning the string true or false. The
>   str parameter will be composed of + and = symbols with several letters
>   between them (ie. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each
>   letter must be surrounded by a + symbol. So the string to the left
>   would be false. The string will not be empty and will have at least
>   one letter.

---

My solution:

```
function simpleSymbols(str) {
    var isSymbol = true;
    var output = " ";
    var symbol = " ";

    if (str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/).length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z') ||
                (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z')) {
                if (i != str.length - 1) {
                    symbol = str[--i] + str[++i] + str[++i];

                    var rgx = new RegExp(/\+[a-zA-Z]\+/);

                    if (!(rgx.test(symbol))) {
                        isSymbol = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    isSymbol = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        isSymbol = false;
    }    

    return isSymbol;
}
```

This worked fine for all test cases.

---

On reviewing code of other submissions, I came across a submission which required only a single line of code:

```
return ('=' + str + '=').match(/([^\+][a-z])|([a-z][^\+])/gi) === null;
```

I'm having trouble understanding how the RegEx used here works. Theoretically, I understand:

- `g` modifier => checks for all matches
- `i` modifier => case-insensitive checking
- `a-z`        => checks the string contains only letters
- `\+`         => refers to the plus sign
- `|`          => match either *alternative1* OR *alternative2*

Thus, if referring to the above, I understand that there are two match conditions:

1. `([^\+][a-z])`
2. `([a-z][^\+])`

So, for a test input such as "+x+y+z+". Am I correct in understanding that the way it checks matches is as follows: +x => x+ => +y => y+ => +z => z+

Further clarification on this RegEx would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://regex101.com/ is your friend !
Technically you are right about what you have said.

[^+] matches everything BUT the plus sign. Now the regex says "if there is a letter that is not preceded by a + or a letter that is not followed by a plus, return the regex".

But since there is "=== null", it will return true only if the above regex has not found anything.

Comment: Also note the `'=' + str + '='`, which makes sure that if the string starts or ends with a letter the regex will match.

Answer (score 0):

`[^\+]` means any character that's not a plus. `[]` is a character group and a `^` at the beginning inside a character group means negate/not. It just says "does this string contain any character that's not a plus, followed by a letter a-z?" which would mean it doesn't follow the rules.